# Chosen plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm tearing my hair out to find why Chosen plugin (http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) doesn't want to work. I have tried different things, such as calling the chosen plugin directly in jQuery, rather than in JavaScript as below, but none of it works. I believe I have called the libraries correct, and the stylesheets, yet none of the functionalities of the plugin are applied to the select boxes. It's probably a simple mistake that I've made somewhere.

This is my  markup, it first calls the stylesheets. `echo $page_htmlhead` calls javascript libraries such as latest jQuery from Google API.

```
<head>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro_V2/scripts/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <title>flyeuro.com</title>  

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"></meta>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Europe's favourite virtual airline!">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro_V2/img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro_V2/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro_V2/scripts/js/main/chosen/chosen.css" />

    <?php 
    /* This is required, so phpVMS can output the necessary libraries it needs */
    echo $page_htmlhead; 
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo SITE_URL?>/lib/skins/flyeuro_V2/scripts/js/main/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".chosen-select").chosen()
    });
    </script>

     // ...rest of <head> code

</head>
```

Inside `$page_htmlhead`...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I finally then display the options for the user on a form...

```
<select class="chosen-select" name="depicao" data-placeholder="Departure Airport">
    <option value="">All</option>

        <?php

        foreach ($airports as $airport)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$airport->icao.'">'.$airport->icao.' - '.$airport->name.'</option>';
        }

        ?>

</select>
```

Comment: can you give a link and the result of a console.log($.fn.chosen) please ?

Comment: The website is on a localhost, sorry. http://pastebin.com/N7L8qJJw

Comment: imo `chosen` is bloated #$@!. use [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js) or [jquery page](http://plugins.jquery.com/selectize/), which comes with its own quirks, but i prefer it to chosen

Comment: What is the Doctype of your document ?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: Try `<!doctype html>` and place the `<scripts>` tags at the end of your file (and after, the javascript invocation of chosen)